# How to create JavaDoc which contains only classes/method annotated with custom Annotation?

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

Situation is like:
The client wants to have a documentation for public API. We do have particular methods documented and annotated with @PublicAPI custom annotation ( to prevent these function from obfuscation ).

Now we would like to generate JavaDocs only for these methods. We are using gradle, and I know that I can filter sources, but it is not sufficient for us - API changes frequently.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom `Doclet` like [this one](https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/1410681). Just adapt the `exclude` method. An then, create a custom `Javadoc` task :

```
task generatePublicAPIDocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  destinationDir = your/dest/dir
  options.docletpath = your/doclet/path
  options.doclet = "com.yourdoclet.TheDoclet"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [ExcludeDocklet](http://www.sixlegs.com/blog/java/exclude-javadoc-tag.html) for years and it works great. Just use a `@exclude` javadoc tag on any class, member, field or package and it will be excluded from the generated javadoc.

Comment: Nice! But, there is one thing, I would like to have annotation `@include` instead of `@exclude`. The client wants only a part of the whole documentation.

Comment: The `@include` functionality is what Javadoc does by default: it would add nothing. Just `@exclude` whatever you don't want your client to see. `@exclude` can be very coarse (you can put it in a `package-info.java` and it will exclude everything in that package) or very granular, at the class member level.